# After browser refresh the session is always destroyed in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, session

I am facing a problem during user login on my website.

I am using AJAX to send the login request to an API URL which will return the JSON response. On the basis of response I set the Rails session, but every time it sets to zero when the page is reloaded or refreshed.

This is the code to set the session:

```
success: function(response) {
            if (response.login_auth == 'sucess'){
              <% session[:login] = 1 %>
              alert(<%= session[:login] %>);
              location.reload();
            }
          },
```

This is the code to destroy the session:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $("#logout").click(function () {
      <% session[:login] = 0  %>
      alert(<%= session[:login] %>);
      location.reload();
    });
  });
```

The login and logout codes are on different pages and included in the header.

Comment: Seriously!!! You really think that will work? Do you know what is server side script and client side script? Your thing wont work as js cant execute server side script. There wont be any session made by that. Client side script cannot execute server side script.

Comment: Rails can build js which runs in the browser, later, and js can talk to rails via a request back to the server.  That is the only way that rails and js can be mixed.